# Sound not playing in python via cmd but works through idle

Tags: python, audio

I tried different ways of playing sound through cmd or any other terminal like that of vscode but python using any module (pygame,winsound,playsound,pyglet,etc.) doesn't play sound. I tried and found that idle plays all the sounds. Is there any way by which even other terminals and ides can play sound?

If you need more info please inform

I even tried using ctrl+g in cmd. it produced sound but when I did the save by using .bat file.It doesn't produce any Sound

Edit:-I work in windows and none other than any terminal like powershell works.It works only through Idle

Edit2:-I used many different codes but the basic code used was

```
import winsound
# for playing note.mp3 file
winsound.PlaySound('click2.wav',winsound.SND_ASYNC)
print('playing sound using  playsound')
```

Comment: What OS and terminals? "Cmd" suggests Windows but I want to make sure. If windows: try PowerShell

Comment: I am working on windows and yeah the basic cmd and it doesn't work in either of it

Comment: Does CMD have access to your speakers?

Comment: how do i check if speakers have access to speakers,i don't know, other apps work fine

Comment: Could you show some code? Thing to test: Add a sleep at the end. IDLE might execute your program with waiting at the end, and others just end and sound ends with it (therefore ends before you can hear anything)